# Auto-Refresh Firebase Database Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, firebase

Good morning, i'm doing a database in firebasse that is showed in a datagridview in visual studio in c#, I wanted to know if that is posssible if when I insert data in the firebase right away refreshing it self automaticly being possible to another computer if using the same program be refreshed in the moment of the criation of the data in the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a firebase trigger (e.g. when a record is inserted), which will then call your application via FCM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases

You can also use `Observables` which give you realtime events:

```
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Database.Query;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
...
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/");
var observable = firebase
  .Child("dinosaurs")
  .AsObservable<Dinosaur>()
  .Subscribe(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Key));
```

https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet

Comment: I'm using the direbase Database for only computers, there's no phones involved. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work :(
I'm using a timer to check second by sencond if something changes in the database but it doesn't make it in time i think.
Here's a piece of the code if it helps:

```
    public Form6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

    }

    IFirebaseConfig ifc = new FirebaseConfig()
    {
        AuthSecret = "#####################################",
        BasePath = "########################################"
        //the hashtags are just to get censored
    };

    IFirebaseClient client;

    private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(ifc);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor verifique a conexão com a sua Internet.");
        }

        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Username");
        dt.Columns.Add("Password");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        textBox6.Select();

        var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        aTimer.Interval = 10000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        FirebaseResponse con = client.Get(@"Cnt/cnt");
        int Counter = int.Parse(con.ResultAs<string>());

        FirebaseResponse con1 = client.Get(@"Cnt1/cnt1");
        int check = int.Parse(con1.ResultAs<string>());

        if (check == Counter)
        {
            
        }
        else
        {
            var set1 = client.Set(@"Cnt1/cnt1", Counter);

            Administrador();
        }
    }
```